# Kafka producer is not recreated with @RefreshScope

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-kafka

I have a config server and several clients that work with Kafka. I would like my clients to work non-stop when I update config properties on a config server.

Here is my configuration setup:

```java
@Component
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "params")
public class ConfigParams {

    private KafkaParams kafkaParams = new KafkaParams(); // some custom params (doesn't matter)

    // ...
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigParams configParams;

    // ...

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    MyKafkaBean myKafkaBean() {
        return new MyKafkaBean(configParams.getKafkaParams()); // here I create my own kafka bean with topics, producers and consumers
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Problem description:**

If I change `bootstrap.servers` property to an incorrect and the kafka producer was invoked, there will be a WARN with a message that producer cannot connect to a kafka broker (that is correct). When I fix this property the connection is back and everything works fine, but I still have WARNs about no connection to the broker for "producer-1" ("producer-2" was created for a new connection).

**P.S.** Consumers work fine without any issues.

**P.S.P.S.** I've already tried to delete producer manually using DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory#reset or DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory#destroy, but it didn't help.

**P.S.P.S.P.S.** I assume the problem is that Kafka saves cache of producers. But I don't know how to solve it.

I'll be grateful for your help.

Comment: `reset()` removes the cached producer(s). I am not sure how your consumers are working, but you probably need to put the producer factory in refresh scope too.

Comment: They both are in a refresh scope. I mentioned in the question, that all beans are recreated successfully. The only problem is WARNs after producer reconnected.

Comment: Doesn't make sense; if the factory is refreshed, the old one will be `destroy()`ed (and producers closed). Please post logs of the refresh someplace. Or better, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I used the `RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent` listener to manually close the producer before the refresh mechanism is processed.
For example:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyRefreshEventListener implements ApplicationListener<RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent> {

    private final MyKafkaBean myKafkaBean;

    public MyRefreshEventListener(@Autowired MyKafkaBean myKafkaBean) {
        this.myKafkaBean = myKafkaBean;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent event) {
        log.info("Refresh myKafkaBean:");
        if (myKafkaBean != null) {
            closeProducer(myKafkaBean);
        }
    }

    private void closeProducer(Producer<String, String> producer) {
        if (producer != null) {
            producer.flush();
            producer.close();
        }
    }
}
```